# java find the longest non-repeating substring- getting weird result

Tags: java

I am doing one classic leet code problem: finding the longest non-repeating substring in a string. Though there are many similar problems on stack overflow. I scratched my head for hours couldn't know why my code produce this weird result. hoping that someone could tell me why my

I am doing it in Java

```
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String s= "wwhoamiUrektxineabcdefghijklmno";
        longestNonRepeatStr(s);     
    }

    public static void longestNonRepeatStr(String tstring) {
        String str="";
        String compare="";
        List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
        int biggest =0;

        //find the nonrepeating string in each loop and add to list str
       for (int i=0; i<tstring.length(); i++) { 
        for (int j=i; j<tstring.length()-1; j++) {
            str+= tstring.charAt(j);
            compare= Character.toString(tstring.charAt(j+1));
            if (str.contains(compare)){
                list.add(str);
                str="";
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    //find the longest nonrepeating string in the list
       for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(biggest).length()< list.get(i).length()) {
        biggest=i;
        }
    }

       System.out.println(list);    
       System.out.println(list.get(biggest));           
    }
```

For input string

```
"wwhoamiUrektxineabcdefghijklmno"
```

output is

```
"abcdefghijklmnb"
```

but it is wrong, the last letter should be "o"

Comment: please also provide the expected output of given string

Comment: @ Pushpendra Kumar, my expected result is "abcdefghijklmno" . could you copy and paste the code in simple Java project and run see if the result is different?

Comment: what's the repeated substring you have in this given `wwhoamiUrektxineabcdefghijklmno` string? I don't see any. `abcdefghijklmno` not justifying the problem statement and input/output.

Comment: rule of thumb: don't declare a variable before it's needed.

Comment: @MohamedSaligh "abcdefghijklmno" is the longest substring of the input String having no repeating characters.

Answer (score 4):

You have several issues (see comments where I corrected the code):

```
public static void longestNonRepeatStr(String tstring) {
  String str="";
  String compare="";
  List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
  int biggest =0;

  for (int i=0; i<tstring.length(); i++) { 
    str = ""; // you must clear the current String before each iteration of the inner loop
    for (int j=i; j<tstring.length(); j++) { // here you were skipping the last character
      str+= tstring.charAt(j);
      // I improved the following condition
      if (j+1 < tstring.length() && str.contains(Character.toString(tstring.charAt(j+1)))){
        list.add(str);
        str="";
        break;
      }
    }
    if (str.length() > 0) { // if you finish the inner loop without breaking, you should
                            // add the current String to the List
      list.add(str);
    }
  }

  for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(biggest).length()< list.get(i).length()) {
      biggest=i;
    }
  }

  System.out.println(list);    
  System.out.println(list.get(biggest));           
}
```

Or, as an alternative, you can add the current String to the List in the last iteration of the inner loop:

```
public static void longestNonRepeatStr(String tstring) {
  String str="";
  String compare="";
  List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
  int biggest =0;

  for (int i=0; i<tstring.length(); i++) { 
    str = "";
    for (int j=i; j<tstring.length(); j++) {
      str+= tstring.charAt(j);
      if (j+1 >= tstring.length() || str.contains(Character.toString(tstring.charAt(j+1)))){
        list.add(str);
        str="";
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(biggest).length()< list.get(i).length()) {
      biggest=i;
    }
  }

  System.out.println(list);    
  System.out.println(list.get(biggest));           
}
```

Further explanation of how you got the output "abcdefghijklmnb":

When `i==16`, your inner loop builds the `String` "abcdefghijklmn". Then it skips the "o", since you ended that loop prematurely (due to `j<tstring.length()-1`). This `String` is not yet added to the `List`, since you haven't detected a repeating character. Now when `i==17`, you append "b" to `str` and get "abcdefghijklmnb". Now you check if the next character "c" already appears in `str`, which is `true`, so you add "abcdefghijklmnb" to your `List`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the last iteration of you your loop structure:

```
for (int i=0; i<tstring.length(); i++) {
  for (int j=i; j<tstring.length() - 1; j++) {
    ...
  }
}
```

If we take your string `wwhoamiUrektxineabcdefghijklmno`, then when `i=30` it'll be processing the last character of the string ("o"), however the length of `tstring` is 31 so the next line (your nested for loop) will not run as `int j=30` and `tstring.length() - 1 = 30`

Instead you should just start your next for loop at `int j = i + 1` and let it run to `tstring.length()`

There are also some logic problems as to when you are adding characters to your string and when you decide that the string needs to be added to your list. Here try this...

```
for (int i = 0; i < tstring.length(); i++) {
  str += tstring.charAt(i);
  for (int j = i + 1; j<tstring.length(); j++) {
    compare= Character.toString(tstring.charAt(j));
    if (str.contains(compare)){
        break;
    } else {
        str += tstring.charAt(j);
    }
  }
  list.add(str);
  str = "";
}
```

Finally, you don't need `str` to be external to your loop. You can instantiate it in your loop (it'll save you about 2 lines of code).

Answer (score 1):

When j reaches the end of the input string without finding a repeated character, you don't add the substring to the list, and you don't reset `str`.

Try something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tstring.length(); i++) {
        String str = Character.toString(tstring.charAt(i));
        for (int j = i + 1; j < tstring.length(); j++) {
            char c = tstring.charAt(j);
            if (str.indexOf(c) >= 0) {
                break;
            }
            str += c;
        }
        list.add(str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the nested `for` when you are in the last cycle task. If the `if` doesn't match you don't add the `str` to list and you don't resent `str` variable. In order to solve the problem I changed a little bit your source code:

```
 public static void longestNonRepeatStr(String tstring) {
        String str="";
        String compare="";
        List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
        int biggest =0;

        //find the nonrepeating string in each loop and add to list str
       for (int i=0; i<tstring.length()-1; i++) { 
        for (int j=i+1; j<tstring.length(); j++) {

            str+= tstring.charAt(j-1);
            compare= Character.toString(tstring.charAt(j));
            if (str.contains(compare)){
                list.add(str);
                str="";
                break;
            }else{
                if (j==tstring.length()-1){
                    str+= tstring.charAt(j);
                    list.add(str);
                    str="";
                }
            } 
         }
       }

       //find the longest nonrepeating string in the list
       for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(biggest).length()< list.get(i).length()) {
           biggest=i;
        }
       }

       //System.out.println(list);    
       System.out.println(list.get(biggest));      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For finding the *longest* nonrepeating substring, you do not need to find (and thus: test) all of them.

You could send a "worm" along the string: it grows (head proceeds) as long as it does not contain repeats, then it shrinks (tail proceeds) as long as there is a repeat.

```
String s = "wwhoamiUrektxineabcdefghijklmno";
String t = "                               ";

int head = 0, tail = 0;
String worm = "";
String caterpillar = "";
do {
    while (head < s.length() && worm.indexOf(s.charAt(head)) < 0) {
        head++;
        worm = s.substring(tail, head);
        System.out.println(t.substring(0, tail) + worm);
        if (worm.length() > caterpillar.length())
            caterpillar = worm;
    }
    if (head < s.length())
        while (worm.indexOf(s.charAt(head)) >= 0) {
            tail++;
            worm = s.substring(tail, head);
            System.out.println(t.substring(0, tail) + worm + "(" + s.charAt(head) + ")");
        }
} while (head < s.length());
System.out.println("Longest: " + caterpillar);
```

Test: https://ideone.com/yMebjx
Output:

> ```
> w
>  (w)
>  w
>  wh
>  who
>  whoa
>  whoam
>  whoami
>  whoamiU
>  whoamiUr
>  whoamiUre
>  whoamiUrek
>  whoamiUrekt
>  whoamiUrektx
>   hoamiUrektx(i)
>    oamiUrektx(i)
>     amiUrektx(i)
>      miUrektx(i)
>       iUrektx(i)
>        Urektx(i)
>        Urektxi
>        Urektxin
>         rektxin(e)
>          ektxin(e)
>           ktxin(e)
>           ktxine
>           ktxinea
>           ktxineab
>           ktxineabc
>           ktxineabcd
>            txineabcd(e)
>             xineabcd(e)
>              ineabcd(e)
>               neabcd(e)
>                eabcd(e)
>                 abcd(e)
>                 abcde
>                 abcdef
>                 abcdefg
>                 abcdefgh
>                 abcdefghi
>                 abcdefghij
>                 abcdefghijk
>                 abcdefghijkl
>                 abcdefghijklm
>                 abcdefghijklmn
>                 abcdefghijklmno
> Longest: abcdefghijklmno
> ```

The character in parenthesis is the one having a duplicate in the shrinking phase.
Of course the implementation would be simpler and faster without the printing, for example the `String`-s could be eliminated completely, the entire algorithm could work with indices on a `char[]` (at the price of having a loop instead of `indexOf()`).

Comment: tried your code, it works but it is not solution I seek, but what is wrong in my code